# how to know mongoid gem version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am new to ruby on rails and am trying to run my first application which connected to MongoDb. How do i know if I have Mongoid gem installed or if I have to install it? and what is the command to know the gem version.

In my rails application *Gemfile* I have added:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'
```

but it gives the error:

```
usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:366:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'mongoid (~> 5.0.0.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Comment: You can run `gem list | grep mongo`  and see if the output shows you some Mongo related gem.

Comment: @SebastianPalma This should be the correct answer to the question title: `how to know mongoid gem version?` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the gem is not present in your local machine. So it's giving you error. Try running command

```
bundle install
```

or you can manually install this gem using console by this command

```
gem install mongoid -v 5.0.0
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!